# How to test throw new error in redux-saga with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga

I test saga with jest framework. I want to test the code when I throw new Error, but I have a problem.

Saga funtion

```
  try {
    const clientId = yield select(selectClientId)

    if (!clientId) {
      throw new Error('Client id is not exists')
    }
    const response = yield call(fetcher, {options})
    yield put(clientReceiveData({ data: response }))
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(clientRequestDataFailure())
  }
}
```

Here's a test saga

```
describe('client fetch data', () => {
  const gen = cloneableGenerator(clientDataFetch)(params)
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(select(selectClientId))

  // @ts-ignore
  expect(gen.throw(new Error('Client id is not exists')).value).toEqual( put(clientRequestDataFailure()))

  // Here expect(received) is undefined
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(fetcher, {options}))
})
```

received to equal with call fetcher is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You already finished the generator , there is no more code to execute, the way to assert that is:
:

`expect(gen.next()).toStrictEqual({ done: true, value: undefined })`

However, for clean code, you **do** expect cases where the client id is undefined, and handle correctly the case already, so it's not an unexpected exception, try:

```js
// generator.ts
function* clientDataFetch(params) {
    //...

    const clientId = yield select(selectClientId)

    if (!clientId) {
        yield put(clientRequestDataFailure())
    } else {
        const response = yield call(fetcher, {options})
        yield put(clientReceiveData({ data: response }))
    }
}
```

```js
// test.ts

describe('client fetch data', () => {
  const gen = cloneableGenerator(clientDataFetch)(params)
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(select(selectClientId))

  // just return the falsy value
  expect(gen.next(undefined).value).toEqual(put(clientRequestDataFailure()))
  expect(gen.next()).toStrictEqual({ done: true, value: undefined })
})
```